# rss as metadata w/o a web presence?

Tags: rss, metadata

I need a fairly simple format to use as metadata (title, creator, description, and some keywords), and thought that I would use RSS 2.0, due to the prevalence of RSS tools.

But I noticed that the "link" element is required, whereas the source data I have is not (and will not be) available via a URL.

Is there an appropriate thing to do besides use a "fake" URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a link element with an empty value.

Comment: I should have added that it's an excellent question, and should be in the RSS FAQ if there was one. :-)